# Having trouble incrementing the age when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react and I am having a hard time trying to increment the age of the person when the button is clicked.

EventComp.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EventComp extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        clicks: 0,
        show: true,
    };
}
 IncrementItem = () => {
     this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks + 1});
 }

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <div class = "person">
        <h1 class="person_h1">
        {this.props.LastName}, 
        {this.props.FirstName}</h1>
        <p>Age: {this.props.Age}</p>
        </div>
        
     <button onClick = {this.IncrementItem}>Celebrate</button>
      
</div>
    
    )
  }
}
export default EventComp;
```

App.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import EventComp from './components/EventComp';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div class ="main">
      <div>
        <EventComp FirstName="Jane " 
        LastName=" Doe " Age = {45}/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <EventComp FirstName = "Joe " LastName = " Doe " Age={88}/>
      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm just confused on how it's supposed to work. There are no errors, but when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the change? I see that you're incrementing `this.state.clicks` but you're not displaying it anywhere, so it's not clear what you're expecting to happen. If you add `{this.state.clicks}` to EventComp's render method output (in the html) you'd expect to see it increment with each click.

Comment: I want the change to be seen in the age HTML, but I don't entirely know what/and where to put the code to make it change.

Comment: A note on your first code section in addition to what others have said (you're not updating *props.age* and not displaying *state.clicks*).  By just using the function and not calling it in your onclick (`onClick = {this.IncrementItem}`), `this` might not be what you think it is in the function.  Try `onClick={this.IncrementItem.bind(this)}` or `onClick={() => this.IncrementItem()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> …having a hard time trying to increment the age…

A common way to do this sort of thing is to have a parent component and a child component (App and EventComp) with responsibilities separated such that the parent manages the state (keeps track of the age) and the child (EventComp) is a "dumb" component that just renders whatever information it's given.

You're already doing most of this by passing the "person" information as props:

```
<EventComp FirstName="Joe" LastName="Doe" Age={88} /> //
```

If you keep track of the age as state in App, then changing "age" will re-render, passing the updated age to EventComp:

```
function App () {
  // create a state variable and a setter function for updating its value
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(88);

  // pass age as a prop:
  return (
    <EventComp FirstName="Joe" LastName="Doe" Age={age} />
  );
}
```

How does age get updated? By calling `setAge`. Here's the same example from above with the addition of a button that increments `age`:

```
function App () {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(88);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setAge(age + 1)}>Increment Age</button>
      <EventComp FirstName="Joe" LastName="Doe" Age={age} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Each click will trigger a re-render showing the new age.

But you want the button in EventComp not in App. How do we connect the button in EventComp to the state in App? By passing the update function as a prop:

```
function App () {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(88);

  return (
      <EventComp
        FirstName="Joe"
        LastName="Doe"
        Age={age}
        onIncrementAge={() => setAge(age + 1)} // <= pass the age incrementing function as a prop
      />
  );
}

function EventComp (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div class = "person">
        <h1 class="person_h1">
          {props.LastName}, 
          {props.FirstName}</h1>
          <p>Age: {props.Age}</p>
      </div>
        
      <button onClick={props.onIncrementAge}>  // <= onClick calls the function provided via props
        Celebrate
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using this pattern, there's a single source of truth about the value of age, and EventComp doesn't need to know or care where it comes from.

---

#### Extending this to handle more than one person:

The examples above demonstrate the fundamental pattern but don't address the need to handle more than one person. Suppose you have a list of people:

```js
const people = [
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 45
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Joe',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 88
  },
]
```

You can iterate over this list, rendering a component for each person:

```
function App () {
  // initial state with 2 people
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([
    { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 45 },
    { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Doe', age: 88 },
  ]);

  return (
    people.map((person) => ( // render an EventComp for each person
      <EventComp
        FirstName={person.firstName}
        LastName={person.lastName}
        age={person.age}
        key={person.firstName} // key is a react thing. ignore for now.
      />
    ));
  )
}
```

Updating a person's age becomes slightly more complicated, but it's still fairly straightforward. We need a function that does the following:

1. Find the person by index (their position in the list)
2. Update their age
3. Update state with the new info

```
const incrementAge = index => {
  const person = people[index];
  person.age += 1;
  setPeople([...people]);
}
```

Pass this new function to EventComp and you're done.

```
function App () {
  // initial state with 2 people
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([
    { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age: 45 },
    { firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Doe', age: 88 },
  ]);

  const incrementAge = index => {
    const person = people[index];
    person.age += 1;
    setPeople([...people]); // spread to a new array so react recognizes it as new
  }

  return (
    people.map((person, index) => ( // render an EventComp for each person
      <EventComp
        FirstName={person.firstName}
        LastName={person.lastName}
        age={person.age}
        onIncrementAge={() => incrementAge(index)} // <= indicate which person via index
        key={person.firstName} // key is a react thing. ignore for now.
      />
    ));
  )
}
```

Notice that we've added the index argument to the map call:

```
people.map((person, index) => {
```

And we're using it when we invoke the click handler:

```
onIncrementAge={() => incrementAge(index)}
```

Voila.

---

You could also pass the person as a single prop:

```
<EventComp
  person={person}
  onIncrementAge={() => incrementAge(index)}
/>

// use props.person.FirstName, etc. in EventComp
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to take a look at this

Comment: the only issue is that I have two different ages to work with. One person = 45 and the other = 88

Comment: Ah. Right. I missed that part in trying to simplify it as much as possible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AimeeCasden Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating age in your IncrementItem function. Instead, you're updating clicks. The reason you're not seeing anything happening is because clicks is not rendered anywhere. If you add a log statement and log clicked, you will see it being updated.

But if you are interested in incrementing age, you first need to add state to age:

```
this.state = {
    clicks: 0,
    show: true,
    age: this.props.Age
};
```

As a note, in the future, props are usually lowercase and I would suggest having that prop be passed in as "age" instead.

The second thing you should do in your increment function is to update the age rather than clicks. If you add a console statement, you will see that the function is actually being invoked. You will also notice that age is being incremented rather than clicks because we are interested in that piece of state. The function should also be defined where the state is defined to retain context.

Note: functions in react are lowercased, components are capitalized. Functions also tend to use a "handle" naming convention, in this case, the function should be named something like "handleIncrementAge"

```
 IncrementItem = () => {
   this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks + 1,
     age: this.state.age + 1
    });

 }
```

Lastly, in your render, because it seems like you are interested in updating state, you want to display that piece of state.

```
<p>Increment Age: {this.state.age}</p>
```

*class attributes should be changed to className because class is a reserved keyword in React. Not doing so will result in your styles not being rendered.

I have attached a CodeSandbox with your code and the recommended changes: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/updateageonclick-bzzco)

[Updating State with React Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)